# Converting json object to c++ object

Tags: c++, json

I'm sending json object from python to c++ program using http, for this example the object is built like so:

```
{
"id":1,
"parameters":{
              "var1":"bla",
              "var2":7,
              "var3":/* base64 encoded binary data */
             }
}
```

The c++ code knows that if `"id" == 1` then we have three parameters first one is `std::string` second is `int` and third is `vector<unsigned char>`. (or `char[],int,unsigned char[]`)

if the `id` is different then different variable types are sent. each `id` corresponds to different C++ Class that have different variable types.

I'm thinking that I should send a struct containing all the values of the parameters from the json like so:

```
{
 char var1[MAX_SIZE];
 int var2;
 unsigned char var3[MAX_SIZE];
}
```

the struct byte array will be encoded in base64, but I dont want to limit the data sent with `MAX_SIZE`

What are the methods/designs it is possible to use in this situation if I want to "cast" each value from the json to objects that c++ can use?

Comment: Why not just send the `json`? I would use a library to parse the `json` when it arrives.

Comment: I'm sending the json, but if the `id` is different then the variable types are also different, so I can't parse it in the same way everytime.

Comment: Use a switch statement on the id? Why are you using MAX_SIZE? Your json parser will know the length of each field and should return it to you so that you can store them in a std::string. You could also just have one field in 'parameters' that is a b64 representation of something like a protobuf or boost serialisation message

Comment: I would use a library such as this to  extract the values: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp

Comment: @James, If i will use serialization in b64 representation, I'm assuming that the data will be sent as struct with limited data char arrays so I will know how many bytes to read in the C++ while serializing, but I don't want to limit the char arrays length.

Comment: @koten then read it into a std::string, I don't know why you think you have to have a MAX_SIZE constraint at all. Your json parser should read the correct length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can extract the information you require from the received `json` data. It uses this `json` parser: [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).

Notice the string data and the decoded binary data are both stored in `std::string` objects.

```
#include <string>
#include <json/json.h>

std::string json_data = R"~(
{
    "id": 1,
    "parameters":
    {
        "var1": "bla",
        "var2": 7,
        "var3": "base64 encoded binary data"
    }
}
)~";

struct parameters_1
{
    std::string var1; // store text here
    int var2;
    std::string var3; // store binary data here
};

std::string base64decode(const std::string& data)
{
    // function to decode base64 data into binary
    return {"decoded data"};
}

parameters_1 parse_1(const Json::Value& parameters)
{
    parameters_1 p;

    p.var1 = parameters.get("var1", Json::nullValue).asString();
    p.var2 = parameters.get("var2", Json::nullValue).asInt();
    p.var3 = base64decode(parameters.get("var3", Json::nullValue).asString());

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    // this is our json document
    Json::Value json;

    Json::Reader reader;
    reader.parse(json_data, json, false);

    Json::Value id = json.get("id", Json::nullValue);

    switch(id.asInt())
    {
        case 1:
        {
            parameters_1 p = parse_1(json.get("parameters", Json::nullValue));

            std::cout << "var1: " << p.var1 << '\n';
            std::cout << "var2: " << p.var2 << '\n';
            std::cout << "var3: " << p.var3 << '\n';
        }
        break;

        default:
            std::cerr << "ERROR: Bad parameter type: " << id.asInt() << '\n';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never knew about R"~( until now. Thanks a lot!